# Get phpsessid after login with a desktop client

Tags: php, go

I have a webpage with a backend on php and I'm sending some data from a desktop client made with go, is there a way to do a get or post request and retrieve a phpsessid like if I were login from the webpage? also i must keep it for at least 5 minutes on the server

Comment: Use [`net/http.Client`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client) with a [`CookieJar` implementation](https://godoc.org/net/http/cookiejar).

Comment: or not use cookie to identity the session, but others like url random